# Move from a controller to different views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a login page with the built in `AccountModel` and `AccountController`. Now I have another controller named `TestController` that sends data from a database to my `TestView`.

What I now wish to to is to send the data that I send from the `TestController` to be displayed within the `AccountView`.

Basically what I am trying to do is to display a feed on the loginpage at the accountview, problem is that the data comes from my `TestController` so I do not now how to pass this data.

So I have this:

1. Controller : AccountController -> Model: AccountModels -> View: Account -> login.cshtml
2. Controller : TestController -> Model: Compare -> View : Test -> index.cshtml

I wanna display the content from #2 within #1 view. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. I highly recommend looking at the tutorial videos [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc)

You could create an action in your TestController that returns a partial view.

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return PartialView("index.cshtml");
}
```

In your login.cshtml view, you would display the partial view from TestController by calling @Html.Action("Test", "TestController")

Comment: Hi, got this to work with some minor edits. Removed .cshtml in "index.cshtml" and removed controller from "TestController" within @Html.Action("Test", "TestController")
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Create an action with return type of ViewResult that will return the overloaded ViewResult which takes in string parameter. That string is the name of your view.

Or you can use RedirectAction to redirect to a different controller's action. I think this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect to Account page together with the data. Below would be my suggestion.

```
public ActionResult PostToAccount() {
    var accountModel = new AccountModel();
    return RedirectToAction("Account", "Account", accountModel);
}
```

If you want ajax based where both Account view and Test view are rendered in a single page. Try the ajax approach

1. Login.cshtml

   <div id="feed"></div>
2. Index.cshtml

View

```
<script>
function postData() {
    $.ajax({
       url: '/Test/PostToAccount'
       data: {
          someData: 'feed'
       },
       success: function(data) {
          $("#feed").data(data.result);
       }
    });
}
</script>
<button onclick="postData"></button>
```

Controller

```
public class TestController : Controller {
     public ActionResult PostToAccount(string someData) {
       var accountModel = new AccountModel();
       accountModel.Feed = feed;
       return View("~/Views/Test/Index.cshtml", accountModel);
     }
}
```